# Use .text to display "Error" but also use it as variable as part of the calculation in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms

My text box that's supposed to show the calculation result after clicking the calculation button. In addition, this text box should display "Error" under specific conditions after the message box.

Because I use `Textbox. Text` as a variable during the calculation, I think the "Error" changed back to the number after I clicked the ok on the message box. I wonder how to keep the "Error " even after closing the message box.

Comment: Firstly, the VS tag is for issues with the IDE, not with code written in VS. ALWAYS read the tag description and only use tags that actually apply.

Comment: As for the issue, if you expect us to be able to tell you what you're doing wrong, you need to show us what you're doing. Please spend some time in the Help Center to learn how to write a proper question. You should have taken the site tour when prompted.

Answer (score -1):

You can determine whether you need to display error in the textbox by determining the return value of the messagebox.

```
If MessageBox.Show("error") = DialogResult.OK Then
    TextBox1.Text = "error"
End If
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.